# What is the difference between these two geometric formulas?

Tags: summation-method

I've seen these two different geometric sum formulas but I don't know when which is used.

$S = a\left(\frac{1-(r^n)}{1-r}\right)$

and

$S = a\left(\frac{1-(r^{n+1})}{1-r}\right)$

Comment: For n terms the first is used. If there are n+1 terms, (eg. You dont count the first term as a term) the second is used.

Answer (score 0):

The second one is the sum
for one additional term.

Note that

$\begin{array}\\
a\left(\frac{1-(r^{n+1})}{1-r}\right)-a\left(\frac{1-(r^{n})}{1-r}\right)
&=a\left(\frac{(1-(r^{n+1}))-(1-(r^{n}))}{1-r}\right)\\
&=a\left(\frac{r^n-r^{n+1}}{1-r}\right)\\
&=a\left(\frac{r^n(1-r)}{1-r}\right)\\
&=ar^n
\end{array}
$

and this is the next term
that is added to the first sum
to get the second sum.